# Performance when awaiting multiple function parameters

Tags: c#, async-await

Does awaiting multiple function paramters boost the performance? Are the parameters functions executed in parallel or would there be no performance gain if compared to non async functions?

Example code:

```
var result = GetGesult(await Func1(), await Func2(), await Func3(), await Func4());
```

Comment: No, they will all be sequentially called and awaited. If you want to kick off all the functions at the same time and then await them all in parallel, you need to rewrite your code to do that specifically.

Comment: [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) may help with understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asynchronous functions will be executed one after another.

You can start all and await when all is complete before assigning results to parameters of next functions.

```
var func1Task = Func1();
var func2Task = Func2();
var func3Task = Func3();
var func4Task = Func4();

await Task.WhenAll(func1Task, func2Task, func3Task, func4Task)

var result = 
    GetGesult(await func1Task , await func2Task, await func3Task, await func4Task);
```

Comment: Is `Task.WhenAll` really necessary? I'd expect `await`s in method call parameters achieve the same.

Comment: I found `Task.WhenAll` is a cleaner way to "tell" other developers/reader about code intentions.

Comment: I agree with @Fabio but technically, no, it is not really needed. It makes the programmer better aware of the fact that the code will block until all the tasks have completed.